# Difference between rows refreshed and rows updated?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I wanted to know that what is the difference between "Rows Refreshed" and "Rows Updated".

As I have seen in the log generated by Oracle LSH Database for one of my tables as below:

```
Rows Refreshed: 20, Rows Inserted: 0, Rows Updated: 0, Rows Deleted: 0
```

I am completely unable to understand the difference between refresh and update.

Thank you so much in advance!

Regards,
Ranjeet

Comment: Is MySQL involved somehow, or can that tag be removed?

Comment: Only an educated guess, but... a row is "refreshed" if no value has changed in any of the columns, the values are "confirmed". On the other hand, a row is "updated" if at least one column value has been updated since the last check.

Comment: @jarlh: I need conceptual answer, It does not matter which database is. Thats the reason I have tagged MySQL too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, this is the log of records that didn't change during the update process.

> **Transactional Processing**
>
> If a record is explicitly updated but if the data remains the same, the system updates its refresh timestamp.

source: [Oracle Life Sciences Data Hub Application Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18315_02/doc.214/e18306/exec.htm)

Comment: Mehdi El Fadil Thanks for the clarification, I got my answer. This make sense.:-)